# I want to use GAS to save images to GoogleDrive and fill in the URL in SpreadSheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using GoogleAppsScript to create a form to submit names and images.
The submitted name and image will be stored in GoogleSpreadSheet, but we would like to store the image in GoogleDrive and store the destination URL.
I think the procedure would be to store the image data in the value of the hidden element when the image is selected, and then create and store the Blob data on the doPost side.

[Code.gs]

```
function doGet(){
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  htmlOutput.setTitle("Image Submission Form");
  return htmlOutput;
}

function doPost(postdata){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(postdata));

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  var image_u = '';
  if(postdata.parameters.image != ''){
    var folder   = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder_ID');
    var imageData = Utilities.base64Decode(postdata.parameters.himage, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
    var fileBlob  = Utilities.newBlob(imageData, 'image/png', postdata.parameters.image + '.png');
    var image     = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
    image_u       = image.getUrl();
  }

  var time    = new Date();
  var name    = postdata.parameters.name.toString();

  sh.appendRow([time,name,image_u]);

  var resultpage = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("result");
  return resultpage.evaluate();
}
```

[index.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" name="main_form" action="URL">
      <div id="card_form">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="image">Image: </label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept=".png" onchange="Upload(this,'himage')">
        <input type="hidden" id="himage">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="trans">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
      function Upload(input, id){
        var file = input.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.fileName = file.name;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(){
          var image = document.getElementById(id);
          image.value = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        };
      }
    </script>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
  </body>
</html>
```

However, with the current code, postdata.parameters.himage after passing the hidden element is undefined.
Therefore, the error "Exception: An unexpected error occurred while retrieving the newBlob method or property in the Utilities object. error.

Please let me know how I can fix this to get the behavior I am looking for.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At HTML and Javascript side, `<input type="text" id="himage">` has no name attribute. By this, `himage` cannot be used as the key.
- And, I thought that in this case, `<base target="_top">` might not be requierd to be used.
- At Google Apps Script side, `postdata.parameters` might be `postdata.parameter`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set the folder ID and your Web Apps URL.

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doPost(postdata) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(postdata));
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var image_u = '';
  if (postdata.parameters.image != '') {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder_ID');
    var imageData = Utilities.base64Decode(postdata.parameter.himage, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
    var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(imageData, 'image/png', postdata.parameter.image + '.png');
    var image = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
    image_u = image.getUrl();
  }
  var time = new Date();
  var name = postdata.parameter.name.toString();
  sh.appendRow([time, name, image_u]);
  var resultpage = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("result");
  return resultpage.evaluate();
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" name="main_form" action="URL">
      <div id="card_form">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <br>
        <label for="image">Image: </label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept=".png" onchange="Upload(this,'himage')">
        <input type="text" id="himage" name="himage">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="trans">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
      function Upload(input, id){
        var file = input.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.fileName = file.name;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(){
          var image = document.getElementById(id);
          image.value = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        };
      }
    </script>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
  </body>
</html>
```

- When this HTML is opened and select a file and click a button, a file is uploaded and created as a file to the folder, and the value is appended to the active sheet with `sh.appendRow([time,name,image_u]);`.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: I was making a common mistake....
Thank you very much for pointing this out.
It worked successfully!

Comment: @初心者にゃんこ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.